# Jmeter-Webdriver Webdriver Sampler - How to execute a script in HtmlUnitDriver?

Tags: webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My Jmeter-webdriver webdriver sampler script is executed finely on chrome browser, whereas when same script is executed the on htmlunitdriver it throws an error.

To configure a HtmlUnitdriver followed the steps:-

Thread Group > Add > Listener >  jp@gc- HtmlUnitDriver Config

```
2016/12/23 14:26:51 ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object Window]. (https://test.html
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593d28', time: '2016-02-11 11:22:43'
System info: host: 'EN09', ip: '192.168.254.2', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
```

Please let me know how to run Webdriver sampler script on Htmlunitdriver successfully

Answer (score 0):

Quick checklist:

1. Are you able to run something "minimal" successfully, i.e.:

   ```
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
   WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
   ```

   If the answer is "No" - it may be installation issue, I would recommend reinstalling the Selenium/WebDriver Support plugins bundle via JMeter Plugins Manager:

   [image: Selenium JMeter Plugins Manager]
2. Are you able to execute your test using HtmlUnitDriver from Java code (without JMeter)?

   If the answer is "No" - check if the issue is present here: https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/ and if not - report it.
3. If you can run your test scenario from Java and not able to run it with JMeter - report it to [JMeter Plugins forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/)

The viable workaround for headless Selenium tests execution using JMeter is [PhantomJS Driver](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PhantomJSDriverConfig/)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for reply,  My program is working very well on other browsers. So, I think,  jmeter-webdriver is installation issue Does it is compatibility issue ? Have you tried before on HTMLUNIT driver ? If not.    can you please try once ?